# Are actuarial and technology related questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Recent advances in information technology might influence the actuarial science.

Would be question from this interdisciplinary domain be on topic here?

Example:

- *What are actuarial implications of rapidly scattering efficiency grades of software teams? (Sources: [DORA/Puppet Labs report DevOps state of the art 2017](https://puppet.com/resources/whitepaper/state-of-devops-report); [DAV Kompass 2017](https://aktuar.de/Dateien_extern/DAV/DAV_Kompass_Ausgabe2_web.pdf))*

Comment: This particular example you give may be too vague to give a concrete answer to (or be far too long). In principle, actuary questions may be a bit specific, but I don't see a reason to prohibit them.

Answer (score 1):

Actuarial questions from a technical point of view are more [statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) than economics or econometrics. I would consider the example you provide as off-topic. Actuarial issues that are linked to or embedded in economic phenomena though are certainly on-topic. It is like the difference between actuarial science and the insurance market.

Comment: hi, Alecos, thank you - then I have to reitrate on "Actuarial questions from a technical point of view". Why are "scattering efficiency grades" a statistics issue rather than an economic? In terms, if you know that a company is 30 times less effective in delivering software than other competitors you would probably have to readjust their actuarial risk calculus, or not? Or do you mean, you would just let it to statistics to prove how success or failure of a company links to its delivery efficiency, without any useful output to the actuarial calculus?

Comment: @J Doe efficiency is _the_ economic issue -but you are asking about its actuarial implications, not about its economic implications

Comment: see edit please